# Why didn't Itachi kill Sasuke?

Tags: naruto

Why did Itachi not kill Sasuke but instead poked his head during their last battle that led to Itachi's death?

Was it because of the clan symbol behind him? Or because he loved him?

Answer (score 4):

I don't know how far you are in the story therefore I don't want to spoil it for you, but Itachi did not plan to kill Sasuke.

He poked his forehead because when he was young he would show his affection towards his younger brother this way.

Since Sasuke was finally able to keep up with Itachi in their fight at the very end Itachi poked his forehead to let Sasuke know that he is still this Itachi, and he still loves him more than anything.